# Method called from another Java file is not running

Tags: java

I am having trouble calling the method *verify()* and *connect()* in the Client_GUI.java file, from my PasswordFrame.java file.

**PasswordCheck.java**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
passwordCheck();
} 

public void passwordCheck(){
String pass = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    if (pass.equals(password))
    {
        Client_GUI clientGUI = new Client_GUI();
        clientGUI.verify();
        clientGUI.connect();
        dispose();
    }
    else
    {  
        System.out.println(pass);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Incorrect password",
                "",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

**Client_GUI.java**

```
    private void b_connectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    {                                          

    PasswordFrame passwordFrame = new PasswordFrame ();
    passwordFrame.show();
    }                                         

    private void tf_video_file_nameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
   // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Client_GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
    public void verify() {

    // SERVER IP ADDRESS INITIALISATION

    // SERVER PORT INITIALISATION
    if (!tf_server_port.getText().isEmpty()) {
        int ServerPort = Integer.parseInt(tf_server_port.getText());
        RTSP_server_port = ServerPort;
        if (ServerPort <= 1024 || ServerPort > 65535) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a port number between 1024 and 65535",
                    "Wrong Port",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Please enter a port number between 1024 and 65535",
                    "Wrong Port",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    // PROTOCOL TYPE INITIALISATION
    ButtonModel protocol_grp = bt_protocol_group.getSelection();
    if (protocol_grp != null){
        String selection = protocol_grp.getActionCommand();

        if(selection.equals("tcp")){
            protocolType = "tcp";
        }
        else if(selection.equals("udp")){
            protocolType = "udp";
        }
    }

    ButtonModel ports_grp = bt_ports_group.getSelection();
    if (ports_grp != null) {
        NoOfPorts = Integer.parseInt(ports_grp.getActionCommand());
    }

    ButtonModel vlc_grp = bt_ports_group.getSelection();
    if (vlc_grp != null) {
        String selection = vlc_grp.getActionCommand();

        if (selection.equals("yes")) {
            vlc_select = true;
        }
    }

    ButtonModel java_vlc = bt_java_vlc.getSelection();
    if (java_vlc != null) {
        String selection = java_vlc.getActionCommand();

        if (selection.equals("yes")) {
            //vlc_player player = new vlc_player();
            java_vlc_select = true;
        }
    }

    }
    System.out.println("All fields verified");

    }
    public void connect() {
    try {
        ServerIP = InetAddress.getByName(tf_server_IP.getText());

        client_fnc client = new client_fnc();
        client.setServerIP(ServerIP);
        client.setServerIP(RTSP_server_port);
        client.setServerIP(VideoFileName);
        client.setframe_start_vlc(50);
        client.setBuffer_Size(bufferSize);
        client.setNoOfPorts(NoOfPorts);
        client.setProtocolType(protocolType);
        client.setFilePath(stringFilePath);
        client.setVLCPath(stringVLCPath);
        client.setencryption_type(encryption_type);
        client.setServerIP(java_vlc_select);
        client.setEncSelected(encryption_select);
        client.setStartVLCatFrame(FRAME_START_VLC);

        try {
            Thread client_thread = new Thread(client);
            client_thread.start();
            client.addObserver(Client_GUI.this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "WRONG IP ", ex);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Please enter a correct IP address.",
                "IP Address wrong",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    System.out.println("Connected to Server");
}
```

When I type in "password" in the password field and click the *jButton1*, the password window just closes without verifying fields in my Client_GUI window. For example, I typed in 20500000 as my Server port. If I call methods *verify()* and *connect()* in the Client_GUI.java file itself, the error message saying  "Please enter a port number between 1024 and 65535" "Wrong Port" would pop up. However, when I call methods *verify()* and *connect()* from the PasswordFrame file, no error message pops up, only "All fields verified" and "Connected to Server" at the end of the code appears. It seems that certain parts of the codes are being skipped. Why is that?

EDIT: Sorry for being vague. The flow I'm looking for is basically this:
1. When *b_button* in the Client_GUI frame is pressed, the PasswordFrame pops up, where users need to enter their password.
2. When the *jButton* in PasswordFrame is pressed, the PasswordCheck method is called and checks whether the text entered i.e *pass*= 'password'
3. If it is, the PasswordFrame is closed and runs the *verify()* and *connect()* methods.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no display for the user of the ClientGUI when called from your other class. You're not showing the constructor, so we do not know what's happening there. is the field initialized to a valid value?

Comment: Possibly when you can Client_GUI file the value for tf_server_port is properly set so its shows appropriate error. When you are calling from passwordcheck you are just initializinf it as new Client_GUI() and invoke the method. Does the constructor initializes or set values for tf_server_port varibale?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between `passwordCheck` and `Client_GUI`? It seems like `PasswordCheck` is an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html), which is being fired from one of your buttons, correct? Ultimately, I'm confused by the line `Client_GUI clientGUI = new Client_GUI();` in that class. It looks like you're instantiating a brand new GUI solely to use the `verify` and `connect` methods, but as Ignazio and Syam S implied, the instance variables those methods access are set to their defaults (probably from the constructor).

Comment: @PaulRichter @Ignazio @Syam Thanks for your comments, I've edited the post above to show some more details in the Client_GUI Code, hopefully it will show more detail.The Client_GUI window will still be open after the PasswordFrame window is launched. I created the `Client_GUI clientGUI = new Client_GUI();` just to call the methods in Client_GUI.

Comment: All variables (such as the tf_server_port) has been initialised with proper values before `tf_server_port.setText("2050");`, I didn't want to paste those initialisations as the code would stretch here. If it's necessary, do tell me and I can copy them.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying to help out. I've decided to simply add the password input field in the Client_GUI window instead of having another separate frame, and simply call this method when *b_button* is pressed:

```
public void passwordCheck(){
String pass = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());

    if (pass.equals(password))
    {
        verify();
        connect();

    }
    else
    {  
        System.out.println(pass);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Incorrect password",
                "",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```